# What's the best way to thread tweets?

Tags: twitter

I want to build a simple q&a app on twitter. And I'm pretty familiar with the API. I was planning to use the "in_reply_to_status_id" attribute, but it looks like that's not available from the search API (...yet, anyways. It appears to be slated for v2).

Any suggestions?

Anyone know of a clever way to figure out if an @reply is in response to a particular tweet? Or is there a way to expose "in_reply_status_id"?

Comment: You can look up all of a user's at replies, and see which ones are in response to the original one in question, but that seems overly round-a-bout and inefficient: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id Is there a simpler way?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552646/whats-a-good-set-of-heuristics-for-threading-tweets - although this one says threading in the title more clearly, so perhaps many will find it in Google more easily

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the user to authorize your application who is being replied **to** then you can pull their [mentions timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/mentions) and see what of their tweets have replies. You can also use the [follow parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#follow) for the Streaming API. And last but not least use the Search API like you mentioned but you will have to request the [full status](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/%3aid) object for each result to see if it is a reply.